# data channel using libjingle C/C++

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

I am looking for a very basic example of establishing a data channel using WebRTC. The `peer_connection` examples given are for audio/video and I am not able to run them to understand the code flow and write code for data channel on my own. I have done this using JavaScript for browser, now want to do the same for native application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the peerconnection.cc for data channel creation API?

I saw this:

```
talk_base::scoped_refptr<DataChannelInterface>
PeerConnection::CreateDataChannel(
    const std::string& label,
    const DataChannelInit* config) {
  talk_base::scoped_refptr<DataChannelInterface> channel(
      session_->CreateDataChannel(label, config));
  if (!channel.get())
    return NULL;

  observer_->OnRenegotiationNeeded();
  return DataChannelProxy::Create(signaling_thread(), channel.get());
}
```

So in the peerconnection_client example, I think you can try create the data channel using peerconnection in the conductor.cc using peer_connection_ inside AddStreams and keep the data channel instance, then try send data using it after the answer is received.

Unfortunately I don't have the compilation env now to I can not try this myself.

Hope you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an old revision of webrtc. There is an example called PCP_MAIN. This example demonstrates the basic file transfer between two peers. However this uses pseudo TCP. This is little hard to getting it work as data channels. Probably you might want to look something around RTP data channels.

I'm curious to know about some examples using SCTP.

Comment: Thanks, currently I am not looking for a specific transport protocol, anything would just do fine. If you have a working simple example for RTP please provide the same, so that I can atleast get something on APIs and their usage.